# if section has class hide nav, when class no longer exists show nav

Tags: jquery, css

I have on my website a number of sections, in some sections the navigation should be hidden but not in all sections.

I have this code:

```
if (!$('section').hasClass("active")) {
    $('nav').addClass('visible');
} else {
    $('nav').removeClass('visible');
}
```

I have already tried this but did not work:

```
if (!$('section').hasClass("active")) {
    $('nav').show();
} else {
    $('nav').hide();
}
```

The section getting an active class when the viewport is on the section and this works.

HTML pastebin: http://pastebin.com/CrEpvDEZ
SCSS pastebin: http://pastebin.com/db3txwRX

Live version: http://staging.madebysteven.nl/

Comment: post your html code please.

Comment: and css of the elements involved.

Comment: when do you use the IF? on a click or something?

Comment: $('section') returns an array of objects... if some have the class active and other do not have, what should return $('section').hasClass("active") ? true or false?

Comment: now I have this:

`if ($('section.begin').hasClass("active") == true) {
    $('nav').hide();
} else if ($('section.work').hasClass("active") == true) {
    $('nav').show();
} else if ($('section.about').hasClass("active") == true) {
    $('nav').hide();
}`

But when you go to another section the nav is not turning back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you wish to hide the nav when a section has the active class:

This should work given you pasted HTML and CSS:

```
$(function () {
    // set visible equal to whether or not a section with the active class exists
    function toggleNav() {
        $('nav').toggle($('section.active.begin').length + $('section.active.about').length == 0);
    }


    // when a section is changed...
    $('section').on('change', function() {
        // re-run the toggle function to determine whether or not to show the nav
        toggleNav();
    });

    // set initial visibility state
    toggleNav();
});
```

Comment: Yes but only the sections section.begin and section.about with class active, section.active is hiding the nav always.

Comment: Cleaned up the answer a bit. Does this yield the desired behavior or does section.about and section.begin alter it further? Can you elaborate on that logic if so? I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: This hides the menu still at section.work and section.contact. but on these sections the menu should be visible.

Comment: I've edited the answer so it only counts sections where class="active begin" and class="active about". Does that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work.
When I do a `console.log()`, I'ts not going into the `('section').on('change')`.
Could this have to do because my sections have a `overflow: hidden;`, and therefore he does not scroll in a normal way?

I have a live version: http://staging.madebysteven.nl/

Comment: What event would cause the active class to be removed? I assume there would be a change to the section, but you can hook into any event. If it's a click, one would use .on('click'...). Make sense?

Comment: I used http://code.pb.io/jquery-snappish/ for the sections, I had to put it inside the script. Like this: http://pastebin.com/U1i7en0s